# Android Game Loop - Thread or Handler?

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm in the process of writing a simple game in Android and wondered whether there's any reason to choose between spawning a thread to run the game or to use a handler.  In my previous apps I always used handlers as I thought they were more efficient but the Lunar Lander sample game uses a separate thread so I'm unsure which is best.

Can anyone shed any light on which this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want to do anything intensive in the UI thread or Android OS will intervene in which case your main game loop is most likely very resource intensive.

> "To summarize, it's vital to the responsiveness of your application's UI to keep the UI thread unblocked. If you have long operations to perform, you should make sure to do them in extra threads (background or worker threads). "

-- [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) from Android docs

Answer (score 1):

In case you're wondering about technical differences, I don't see how the `Thread` run by Lunar Lander could be any different from the `Runnable` used by a `Handler`, except that the `Runnable` runs on the UI thread. The reason Lunar Lander uses a `Thread` is to get the execution off the UI thread.

The reason is that the usual game architecture wants to run through a main loop that updates and then refreshes the screen as fast as possible. In addition, most games don't really use the UI for much, and instead draw directly to the canvas/surface.

If you're doing these things, you'll want to use a separate thread for the main loop. If you put the loop in the UI thread, you'll get an ANR. Handlers can be used to send data back to the UI thread, but in the game part of games (menus, loading screens, etc are different), they usually aren't used too much.